# How to work with the current record being created in an SQL trigger

Tags: sql, triggers

I dont know if I am doing this correctly but here goes...

I want to write an SQL trigger that looks at the current record being inserted and reacts to it but my question is; how do I work with data in this record?

For example, if a new order was being inserted in to the orders table, I want to be able to get the customer name from that order to use in some logic (lets say an email for now).

I had thought about using a `SELECT` statment that returned the `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY DESC` but this seems a bit sloppy to me?

Any advice would be greatly received!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL Server, or another RDBMS? If SQL Server, which version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MS SQL Server, you need to query the [inserted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) table to get the records that are being inserted.

Although, the `inserted` table will include all rows being inserted for that transaction.  Processing rows on a row by row isn't generally advised in SQL Server. You should be using a set based approach.

Obviously, if only one row is being inserted then there will only one row in the `inserted` table.

Comment: When you say that you shouldn't work on a row by row basis, do you mean that it's not possible / best practise to use some kind of 'for each'?

Comment: @Jimbo: I am saying that generally it's not best practice. I'm not saying that it doesn't happen but where possible it's best to avoid it.  You can use while loops or a cursor but the performance is usually poor.